# influxdb query for grafana with grouped data

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm using influxdb to store some service metrics. These are simple metrics, such as read bytes or active connections. Then, with grafana, I'm composing some visualizations on top of this.

Displaying something as 'read bytes' is quite simple, it's basically summing up values, grouped by a time interval.

```
SELECT sum("value") FROM "bytesReceived" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(0)
```

It's on the 'active connections' that I'm having some trouble figuring out. These are tcp sockets connected to a service, where the measurement is the number of connected sockets; this is updated whenever a socket connects or disconnects.

If I had only one instance of the service, this would be easy, I would just do something like

```
SELECT last("value") FROM "activeConnections" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(0)
```

The thing is that there are multiple instances of the service, which are created dynamically. The measurement is written with the additional tag 'host', that is populated with an id for the runtime service.

So, let's get into the data points.

```
select * from activeConnections where time > '2018-05-16T16:00:00Z' and time < '2018-05-16T16:10:00Z'
```

This spits out something like

```
time                host         value
----                ----         -----
1526486436041433600 58e5bd04a313 5
1526486438158741000 58e5bd04a313 4
1526486438712713000 58e5bd04a313 3
1526486811218129000 29b39780fd7b 4
```

So as you can notice, we end up with 3 connections on one host and 4 on another. The problem in hand is... displaying that data merged as a whole, where that last line should be 7, for example.

I tried grouping data by host

```
select last(value) from activeConnections where time > '2018-05-16T16:00:00Z' and time < '2018-05-16T16:10:00Z' group by host
```

which gives me the last value for each group

```
name: activeConnections
tags: host=29b39780fd7b
time                last
----                ----
1526486811218129000 4

name: activeConnections
tags: host=58e5bd04a313
time                last
----                ----
1526486706993942700 3
```

Also tried using a subquery

```
select * from ( select last(value) from activeConnections where time > '2018-05-16T16:00:00Z' and time < '2018-05-16T16:10:00Z' group by host )
```

But I get the same problem, where I don't know how to group things nicely for grafana with a time interval.

Does any care to comment and help? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to get. `select last(value) from activeConnections where time > '2018-05-16T16:00:00Z' and time < '2018-05-16T16:10:00Z' group by time($__interval), host
` should give you many lines in graph panel (one per host tag). Or you want to plot one line with sum() of last(value)_per_host_tag - aka "total activeConnections"? Then you'll need subqueries: group by time in outer select and group by time,host in inner one. Optionally replace last() with avg() or max() in inner query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I want to plot a line with the sum of all hosts. I'm fiddling with subqueries to see if I can get to a result.

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

I seem to have found a solution. It's a shame that Grafana doesn't support sub-queries, so the query needs to be inserted manually with raw view. There's an issue open [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/7692).

So, what I needed was a way to group all the hosts value into a single plot line. That can be achieved with the following query:

```
SELECT sum("value") FROM (SELECT last("value") as "value" FROM "activeConnections" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval), "host") GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(previous)
```

I was close before, but failed to notice that in the inner select, if you don't give a name to the resulting select, it comes out as "last" by default. So I was trying to sum up "value", but the field didn't exist out of the sub-query.

Hope this helps someone. Thank you Yuri, for your comment. It pointed me into the right direction.